# DirectoryInfo.Create truncating directory name on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

We're moving our application to a new windows server (2012 to 2016).  The code and the database are the same and working properly on 2012 (VS 2012 .net Framework 4.5). Basically when uploading a file the application puts the file in certain directories.  If the directory doesn't exist is creates it. 
Code for creating the directory:

```
     var fpath = Path.Combine(FileSystemHelper.RepositoryAttaPath, vault);
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(fpath);
        //create the folder if does not exists
        if (!di.Exists)
            di.Create()
```

This works fine on the 2012 server but truncates the vault folder on the 2016 server.  For example
If creating a new folder called RASTER under c:\tmp the following occurs:

2012 server c:\tmp\RASTER created.
2016 server c:\tmp\RAS created.

Same code just different servers. What could be causing the truncated name?

Comment: Are you sure `vault` is always `RASTER`?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. Please verify that real minimal example with all strings hardcoded work the way post claims and [edit] the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Raymond Chen No the vault isn't always Raster it could also be Vector.  But on the Windows 2016 server it only creates folders RAS or VEC.  On the windows 2012 server it creates the RASTER or VECTOR folder correctly.

Comment: Log the `di.FullName` to make sure it's the path you think it is. Perhaps somebody is renaming the directory after you create it.

Comment: After doing so more digging I have come to find out that the issue is with the Oracle client 12.1 I was using.  It is known to truncate return varchar values..  The vault paramater was determined through a stored proc and was getting truncated by the oracle client.  Removed the client and reinstalled oracle 11R2 client and everything is working.